# Separating strings in R when they are different lengths/contents

Tags: r, string

Running into trouble when trying to create a new column (or columns) that separates outs contents of a column (characters, different length strings) in R.  The column contains separated characters/text per observation (populated with contents of a drop down list in a questionnaire).  The problem I am running into seems to be based around the fact that the values are all different lengths with different entries.  Specifically, I only care about 2 possible entries, and I want to find out if those are TRUE/FALSE (or 1/0) per observation, or alternatively separate out the contents of the column into multiple columns.  When i try an ifelse statement, it sometimes works but most of the time it does not.  Examples below:

[image]

And return either values assigned to them "IF" they have one or both of the specific reasons listed
"Disabled/unable to work|"
"Lack of eligibility documentation/identification"
(note, this could be in separated columns or within the same column if either one is included)

Something like this

[image]

I have tried this to create 2 binary columns if it meets the conditions, but it doesn't always return the correct value.

```
df %>% mutate(EligibilityDocs = 
ifelse(Reason == "Lack of eligibility documentation/identification",   1, 0),
Disabled = ifelse(Reason == "Disabled/Unable to Work", 1, 0))
```

I have also tried separating into multiple columns, but that returns only letters in the columns, so I know its definitely not correct:
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - thanks!

Comment: @jpsmith can you please explain here? I understand the link you you shared. However, I pasted the code into the body of the query.  Did I do something wrong here? Please advise.

Comment: Among the multiple reasons the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12109788) in the above link states, "Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem." The code you provided is limited in use if we dont have the data to reproduce it the problem. It would be advised to edit your question to include the data as reproducible code, not images

Comment: I see - thank you. I am new to actually posting questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find strings that contain your desired string, even if they contain other text as well. There are a few ways to do this, but I will use a `tidyverse` approach since that is what your example shows.

The [`stringr`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/) package in the `tidyverse` contains lots of helpful functions for parsing strings. [`str_detect`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_detect.html?q=str_detect#null) checks if a string contains your given string or regular expression.

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    EligibilityDocs = ifelse(
      str_detect(Reason, "Lack of eligibility documentation/identification"),
      1,
      0
    ),
    Disabled = ifelse(
      str_detect(Reason, "Disabled/Unable to Work"),
      1,
      0
    )
  )
```

If you are interesting in accomplishing this in base R, you can use `grepl("Disabled/Unable to Work", df$Reason)`.

Comment: Following up on this query @mfg3z0.  The above worked in multiple scenarios with different spreadsheets. I have now run into a new data frame where the above options using stringr doesn't return the correct binary response.  I have exactly 5 strings I am searching for.   "Family member(s)|Other adult(s) outside the program|Peers|Other community|Adult outside the program" . From what I can tell, only the "Peers" opton returns a response. Is there any concievable reason why this could be?